# any one help me, getting error with my rails server when i adding authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Couldn't find User with 'id'=8

Extracted source (around line #13):

```rb
def current_user 
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id] 
end

def require_user
```

Rails.root: C:/Users/AB COMPUTER/SecureSite

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:17:in`require_user'
Request

Comment: The error kind of gives it away. You do not have a user with `id` of `8`

Comment: Just refresh your `chrome` cache, or create a `user` with the `id` of `8` in your rails console

Comment: i know that error message say that but when i try to create a new user with id:8 i get the same error and seed.rb couldn't update , the problem begin when i update db:migrate with db:rollback and old user with id 8 deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This error tells you that you do not have a user with an `id` of 8.

Open your browser developer tools and clear the sessions/cookies and try again, in **chrome** you will find those under **Resources** tab.

Comment: i know that error message say that but when i try to create a new user with id:8 i get the same error and seed.rb couldn't update , the problem begin when i update db:migrate with db:rollback and old user with id 8 deleted.

Comment: Clean your sessions/cookies, if you could reset your database `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` and it will work.

Comment: thank everyone, the problem was solved , now i can continue with my job,